# Dojo and Firebug

Tags: javascript, dojo, firebug

I just started a new project with the Dojo toolkit, and no sooner did I drop my dojo.js script tag in than firebug started telling me

```
Could not load 'dojo._firebug.firebug'; last tried './_firebug/firebug.js'
```

I know dojo has a reputation for bad debugging messages, but this is ridiculous....

If anyone has any ideas about this I would appreciate it.

Comment: You have any source code to go with that error message?

Comment: lol that's the thing, the source code is: <script type='text/javascript' src='js/dojo.js'></script> .... and that's it

Comment: I love Dojo, but I agree Dojo's error messags suck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put it on a web server, per [this thread](http://www.nabble.com/newbie-question-td19229349.html) -- probably a local web server that only serves to your own machine, of course, for development purposes.

Comment: Ah thanks...I literally just started this project, haven't even set it up on my apache yet.  Thanks!

Comment: @Paul, if this "still gives [you] that error" you need to unaccept the answer. Otherwise delete your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to work without a web server.
go through the below mentioned steps.

http://www.dojotoolkit.org/support/faq/why-does-dojo-fail-load-file-urls-firefox-3

Set Security.fileuri.strict origin policy to false and retry.

Answer (score 1):

Why not start with [the skeleton code?](http://sitepen.com/labs/guides/?guide=DojoQuickStart#firstSteps) When in doubt, go with the beginner's tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue on Firefox, if you access a local HTML page that is not being passed through a server, Firefox will give you errors because if does not allow directory traversal.

Other browsers allow local directory traversal though.

The best solution is to run the page through a server (local or remotely) since a server allows this type of directory traversal to occur.

Answer (score 0):

`Dojo.js` should be in the `root/Dojo` folder.
It should work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Like people have said the error comes when `firebug.js` isn't there. I got the same error but it was because I created a custom build but left my `DjConfig` value `isDebug` to be `true`.

As soon as I changed it to `isDebug:false` dojo quit trying to load firebug.